# ReferenceError: window is not defined in redux component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  value: window.innerWidth
};

const screenSizeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'screenSize',
  initialState,
  reducers: {    
    screenSizeResize: (state, actions) => {
      state.value = actions.payload
    },
  }
})

export const {screenSizeResize } = screenSizeSlice.actions

export default screenSizeSlice.reducer
```

So I have this component, and I have this error:

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

If I use `typeof window !== 'undefined'` for example to solve it, it will cause hydration. I'm using `nextjs` btw.

How to solve this problem?

I tried conditional rendering but it caused hydration.

Comment: Servers don't have a `window` object. See if using [next-redux-wrapper](https://github.com/kirill-konshin/next-redux-wrapper) helps.

Comment: Don't assume `window` will be available at the root level of the js file. Maybe you can dispatch a `screenSizeResize` action after you inititialise the store in during client-side hydration (which happens client size and has the `window` object available).

Comment: However, _do_ assume that [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) exists, which is the same as `window` in the browser, but not in Node/servers/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the app starts, we don't have the window object yet. Because it is only available after the component mounts. So, I would say you have to move that code into useEffect() or if you are using class-based components, move to componentDidMount()

For the Functional Component.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  value: ""
};

const screenSizeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'screenSize',
  initialState,
  reducers: {    
    screenSizeResize: (state, actions) => {
      state.value = actions.payload
    },
  }
})

export const {screenSizeResize } = screenSizeSlice.actions

export default screenSizeSlice.reducer
```

Give it an empty value at first and when the app mounts that in the App.js, inside an useEffect set this value.

```
const { screenSizeResize } = useSelector(screenSizeSlice)

useEffect(() => {
   screenSizeResize(size)
})
```

I guess this will work, inform me if it worked.

Comment: yeah i thought about this one before i tried it but it did not work because 
  style={{ translateX:ScreenSize>=768?translateXEight:translateXEightMob }}
but i made changes int the 
  const translateXEight = ScreenSize>=768? useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0.1, 1], [0, 800]): useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0.1, 1], [0, 400]);
  style={{ translateX:translateXEight }}
and now it works